# Difference between substring and string in java

Tags: java, string, substring, equals

```
class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Hiabc";
    String b = "abc";
    String c = "abc";
    System.out.println(a.substring(2,5)==b);
    System.out.println(b==c);
}
}

output:
false
true
```

As far as I understand, Java's == look for addresses of the two compared objects. Yet, I don't understand why b==c is true because they must have different addresses. Also, if b==c, then why is a.substring(2,5), which is "abc" == b false?

Comment: Because `substring` creates a **new object**. `b` and `c` refer to the *same* String in the pool.

Comment: could you explain more about the "pool"? You mean Java has all library of strings?

Comment: Google it, there are infinite resources about Java Strings Pool.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, Java's == look for addresses of the two compared objects.

Almost correct. Java uses references not addresses, e.g. a reference is strongly typed: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

> why b==c is true

The variable `b` and `c` are initialized with the same string reference, because they reference the same [string literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) `"abc"`.

> why doesn't substring expression reference the string literal "abc"?

Because the javadoc of [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) says

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

So the method does not ensure that a reference to a string from the constant pool is returned. If you want this you have to do

```
a.substring(2,5).intern()
```

and than

```
a.substring(2,5).intern()==b
```

will be `true`.

Comment: why doesn't substring expression reference the string literal "abc"?

Answer (score 0):

Never compare strings with == in Java.
Use .equal or .equalIgnoreCase methods instead.

The difference between a.substring(2,5) and b is because substring created another String object and it's on a different location than b. It's not about the characters ...